# XML DOM Creating Mixed Content

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxp

I need to insert an element in the middle of another element's text. Given here is "before" and "after" that I want

**Before**

```
<element1> This is content of element1 </element1>
```

**After**

```
<element1> This is <element2></element2> content of element1 </element1>
```

Any ideas how to achieve this....I am using Java Dom API.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'll need to remove the existing text node(s), and then create three new nodes:

- The text before `<element2>`
- `<element2>`
- The text after `<element2>`

Add all of those to `<element1>` after removing the existing text node(s).

Comment: I was hoping I would not need to do that.

Comment: @user1752247: Why? You need to control exactly where it's split anyway - and this will be a tiny amount of work. (It's really not that hard to add the nodes.) Have you tried implementing this and run into any problems?